# Is it possible to develop large applications (Enterprise level) in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to develop applications like Facebook using .NET?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you *really* asking a yes/no question?

Comment: I believe StackOverflow is built in .NET.

Comment: Most of the applications are developed using Java. I am curious to know if there is huge application built using dotnet

Comment: Orleans, which is an actor framework is built in .Net and runs the Halo game's backend.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many large multinational organizations depend on the .net framework.

A lot of organizations do not publish their full tech stack however you can see this with tools like [this](https://trends.builtwith.com/websitelist/ASP.NET) or looking at the job adverts on the [job page of stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

In addition, StackOverflow is built with .net see [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/21/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In fact .NET isn't designed for hobbies level stuff it's designed for enterprise level feel free to use this powerful framework no matter if you're a beginner or a large company, you can always build your own solutions on top of it.